# Using variable for a key - Mongo/Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to pass `MPN` as a variable but its taken as a literal:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) { console.log('err); }
  else {
    for (var key in products) {
      supplier = products[key];
      MPN = sanitizeKey(keys[product]['MPN']);
      console.log( typeof(MPN), MPN ); // => string manufacturesPn

      findDocument(db, product, { MPN : '960-000584' });
      // => No document(s) found in [collection] with {"MPN":"960-000584"}!
      // Expected: {"manufacturesPn":"960-000584"}
    }
  }
  db.close();
});
```

... and this is the `findDocument` function:

```
var findDocument = function(db, collection, queryObj, callback) {
   var cursor = db.collection(collection).find( queryObj );
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
         return doc;
      } else {
         console.log('No document(s) found in ' + collection + ' with ' + JSON.stringify(queryObj) + '!');
      }
   });
};
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

`MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) { console.log('err); }
  else {
    for (var key in products) {
      supplier = products[key];
      MPN = sanitizeKey(keys[product]['MPN']);
      console.log( typeof(MPN), MPN ); // => string manufacturesPn
      //this is how to asign variable as a key
      var query = {};
      query[MPN] = '960-000584';
      findDocument(db, product, query);
      // => No document(s) found in [collection] with {"MPN":"960-000584"}!
      // Expected: {"manufacturesPn":"960-000584"}
    }
  }
  db.close();
});`

When you create new object like this

```
var a = "test";
var b = {a: 1234}; <- a is just a key not variable value.
```

Also in es6 you can do like this

```
var query = {
   [MPN]: "yourValue"
}; // <- {"manufacturesPn":"yourValue"}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `[var]` worked like a charm! However, it still says no documents although I can search with the exact same object in RockMongo, could just it my another silly mistake though.

Comment: Hm...Only thing that i think can be responsible for that is DB.close... Maybe try to run it after findDocument callback is called. findDocument code looks OK to me.